# cant get twitter bind to work?

Tags: javascript, twitter

i am trying to run a little script before redirecting to twitter but it does not show the 'hi' alert? I used this as a reference:https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm6.aspx.cs" Inherits="iFrame.WebForm6" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
                 // Do something there
                 alert('hi');
             });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html"
                style="width: 130px; height: 20px;"></iframe>
        </div>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work ( http://jsfiddle.net/JbJ9T/ ) fine, but I've noticed that you're missing an opening `<html>` tag. I could imagine that this might cause some trouble.

Also, check the console in e.g. Firefox or Safari for Javascript errors and/or notifications that something is missing or in a wrong location if the suggestion above doesn't help.